# Couldnt write a regex to string

Tags: javascript, string

I have string like that
`test_i|min:10|sym:iterator`. First part is a name and always will be, other parts is optional. Regex need to test string like it and if it bad (like `min:10|sym:iterator` or `test_i|min:10sym:iterator` or `test_i|min:|sym:iterator` etc) return false from test method(regex.test(string)). How regex fits?

Comment: I use regex /[a-z]\w*([|]?\w+:\d+|\w+)*/gi but it returns true in any of the above variants like `min:10|sym:iterator` or `test_i|min:10sym:iterator` or `test_i|min:|sym:iterator`

Comment: Hi  Don't keep this information in the comments - update your question so everybody can see the regular expression, not just by reading all comments.

Comment: Also be aware that `|` in regular expressions means an alternation ("this OR that"). See documentation: [regex | docs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). You can write `[|]?`, this one is correct, but the other one you should escape as `\|` to mean the | character.

Comment: What's wrong with `min:10|sym:iterator`? I see two keys and values here.

Comment: *"other parts is optional"*: you then give examples where other parts are omitted, and say they are invalid? A paradox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this to match:

`test_i|min:10|sym:iterator`

So some identifier, then some key and a value.

You want this to not match:

- `min:10|sym:iterator` (No identifier at the beginning)
- `test_i|min:10sym:iterator` (| missing between two key/values)
- `test_i|min:|sym:iterator` (missing value)

Using this regular expression will only accept your first test case and excludes the rest:

```
^\w+(\|\w+:(\d+|\w+))*$
```

- `^` and `$` means your expression must match all of the input text
- `\w+` just expects any name at the start
- `\|` is the `|` symbol (must be escaped as explained in the comments)
- `\w+:(\d+|\w+)` makes sure the value is either a number or a string
- `()*` repeats this pattern for as many matches as there are

See regex101 playground here to experiment:
https://regex101.com/r/ncllOW/1

Comment: Thanks, it works nice! And I found out a few new tricks) Will continue studying regex.

Comment: Good stuff, keep studying 